# ASP .NET MVC3 WebGrid footer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I really cannot find any good solution to realize ASP .NET MVC3 WebGrid footer which has some total values...

Any clue how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776534/add-row-in-webgrid

Comment: Thanks! But this is very ugly solution...

Comment: yes I agree. I would actually use other controls like Telerik or DevExpress MVC Extensions. it pays off with the big amount of features they offer and allows you to make much more professional looking MVC applications. Telerik MVC are also free of charge if you release under GPL like license...

Comment: Definitely you are right... But my customer don't like to buy any extra controls... :)

Comment: You can try to use this http://datatables.net/ it's free and works ok, and it can be customized a lot. plus you can use JSON to transfer the data and there is an MVC controller for it.

Comment: Thanks for the input but  datatables.net doesn't has any footer to keep total valuse of the columns...

Answer (score 0):

I assume best approach is to calculate total value and pass it in model and just assign to some label that is positioned under the grid.